# Bert Tokenizing error ValueError: Input nan is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers

Tags: python, nlp, classification, tokenize, bert-language-model

I am using the Bert for text classification task , when I try to tokenize one data sample using the code:

```
encoded_sent = tokenizer.encode(
                        sentences[7],                       
                        add_special_tokens = True)
```

it goes well but when ever i try to tokenize the whole data using the code:

```
# For every sentence...
for sent in sentences:
    
    encoded_sent = tokenizer.encode(
                        sent,                       
                        add_special_tokens = True)
```

it gives me the error:

```
"ValueError: Input nan is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers."
```

I tried in English data that was successfully tokenized by someone and I get the same error.
This is how i load my data:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("/content/DATA.csv",header=0,dtype=str)
DATA_COLUMN = 'sentence'
LABEL_COLUMN = 'label'
df.columns = [DATA_COLUMN, LABEL_COLUMN]

df["sentence"].head
```

and this is how i load the tokenizer:

```
# Load the BERT tokenizer.
print('Loading BERT tokenizer...')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('aubmindlab/bert-base-arabert')
```

a sample of my data:

Original:  مساعد نائب رئيس المنزل: لم نر حتى رسالة كومي حتى غردها جيسون تشافيتز

Tokenized:  ['مساعد', 'نائب', 'رئيس', 'ال', '##منزل', ':', 'لم', 'نر', 'حتى', 'رسال', '##ة', 'كومي', 'حتى', 'غرد', '##ها', 'جيسون', 'تشافي', '##ت', '##ز']

any suggestions please?!

Comment: Please post some more code. Can you show an example of sentences variable?

Comment: Please recheck, I provide more information. @anakin87

Comment: Please insert `print (sent)` and `print (type(sent))` inside the for loop and report the results. Probably there is something wrong there.

Comment: Thank you so much! the dataset had some float data, under the name "nan".

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your data contain NAN values, to surpass this issue, you have to eliminate NAN values or transform all data to string (local solution).

Try using:

```
encoded_sent = tokenizer.encode(
        str(sent),                       
        add_special_tokens = True)
```

If you're sure that the dataset doesn't count NAN values you might use that solution, or to detect if your dataset contain NAN values you might use:

```
for sent in sentences: 
    print(sent) 
    encoded_sent = tokenizer.encode( sent, add_special_tokens = True)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It would improve the quality of your answer if you explained how your answer works. Even just a short summary can help a lot!

Comment: it seems like his data contain NAN values, to surpass this issue, he has to eliminate NAN values or transform all data to string (local solution). If he's sure that the dataset doesn't count NAN values he might use that solution, or to detect if his dataset contain NAN values he might use:
for sent in sentences:
    print(sent)
    encoded_sent = tokenizer.encode(
                        sent,                       
                        add_special_tokens = True)